# Model lift curve: sort by predicted or actual?

Tags: predictive-models, modeling, data-mining

When determining the effectiveness of a model (continuous response variable), a common technique is to sort by the predicted value and split into equal-sized buckets e.g. 10 deciles. Then compare the mean of the predicted vs. actual within each bucket to see how good is the model.

But why don't we sort and bucket by the actual value instead of the predicted value? Wouldn't this have the advantage of comparing multiple models against one another, whereas sorting by predicted value limits you to just one model?